# Formula for the Lie derivative of $fX$ on functions (proving that the Levi-Civita connection is a connection)

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, lie-derivative

I am currently in the process of reading *Riemannian Geometry* by Gallot, Hulin and Lafontaine in order to learn more about differential and, well, Riemannian geometry.
I'm more of a functional analyst so I'm trying to get accustomed to all the algebraic and geometric concepts and arguments, but not without issues...

Theorem $2.51$ is the theorem about the existence and uniqueness of the Levi-Civita connection, denoted by $D$, on a (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ (only the non-degenerescence of $g$ is used, hence $g$ can have any signature). In this book it is proved using a coordinate-free approach via the Koszul formula:
$$2g(D_XY, Z) = L_X(g(Y,Z)) + L_Y(g(Z,X)) - L_Z(g(X,Y)) + g([X,Y], Z) - g([Y, Z], X) - g([X,Z], Y)$$

I have no problem with the uniqueness part, but I have trouble proving that this expression will serve to define a connection, i.e. a $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear map $D: \Gamma(TM)^2 \to \Gamma(TM)$ which is $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$-linear in the first variable and satisfies the Leibniz formula in respect to the second variable.

The advice from the authors given in that part of the proof suggests to check that the RHS of the formula, let's call it $P_{X,Y}(Z)$, is $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$-linear in regards to $Z$. However, what I have using the properties of the bracket and the metric and what I learned about Lie derivatives is this:
$$P_{X,Y}(fZ) = f P_{X,Y}(Z) + fL_Z(g(X,Y)) - L_{fZ}(g(X,Y))$$
This should be good if the Lie derivative $L_X$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$-linear in $X$ but at this step I wasn't too sure, because there is no formula given for $L_{fZ}$ relative to $L_Z$ and $f$ as far as I could see, be it in this book or on the net, including MSE.

Ideally I would have liked to prove it coordinate-free but here's my simple-and-to-the-point attempt using local charts:

> Let $(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ be local coordinates on a chart $U$ on $M$ and $h \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$. In these coordinates, we have:
> $$L_{fX}(h) = \sum_{i = 1}^n (fX)_i \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{i = 1}^n f X_i \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i} = f L_X(h)$$

There was a formula on Wikipedia and on MSE for the action of the Lie derivative on differential forms: $$L_{fX}(\omega) = fL_X(\omega) + df \wedge \iota_X\omega$$ but I'm not sure whether this works on functions considering that the interior product $\iota_X$ is the contraction $c_{1,1}(X \otimes \cdot)$ which eats contravariant tensors of type $(0, q)$ for $q \geq 1$, and thus not functions. What does worry me a bit is that this does not seem to be $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$-linear in regard to $X$?
Hence my question is:

> Is the action of the Lie derivative on functions $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$-linear in $X$? If not, what is wrong with what I've written?

Comment: A function $g$ is a $0$-form. Hence, $\iota_Xg$ is a $(-1)$-form, which is by definition/convention $0$.

Comment: @Didier Oh I wasn't aware of that convention, but I suppose it makes sense.

Comment: Do you know about de Rham cohomology? It makes perfectly sense especially for this

Comment: @Didier I think I've seen that term before but I don't know anything about it.

Comment: You will encounter this notion if you pursue reading this excellent book. Maybe it will clarify the purpose of the convention

Comment: @Didier Your comment is essentially an answer to OPs question. This is a coordinate free argument that shows the Lie derivative is $C^{\infty}$-linear. OPs coordinate approach works as well.

Comment: Why use the term "Lie derivative" here at all? It makes everything sound more complicated than it really is. The Lie derivative of a function with respect to a vector field is just the directional derivative of the function in the direction of the vector field, $$ L_Xf(p) = \langle df(p), X(p)\rangle. $$ This makes it clear that $L_{\phi X}f = \phi L_X f$.